# php removing array element from 2 dimension array, knowing element name in 2'nd dimension only

Tags: php, arrays

sorry, the title might be confusing but this should clarify.

I want to remove $fruits['banana'] record because $fruits['banana']['shelf_life'] expired.

I can do a foreach to find the ['shelf_life'] value I'm checking, but how do I find it belongs to $fruits['banana'] to delete it?

```
$fruits=array(
'apple' => array ('shelf_life' => 10),
'banana' => array ('shelf_life' => 5),
'orange' => array ('shelf_life' => 7)
)

$shelf_time = 6

// I want to remove expired fruits from array

foreach($fruits as $v1){
    if ($v1['shelf_life']<$shelf_time)
    //remove matching $fruits array record 'banana'... how?
}
```

The result I want is

```
$fruits=array(
'apple' => array ('shelf_life' => 10),
'orange' => array ('shelf_life' => 7)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter it based on value of `$shelf_time`.  Use `>` or `>=` whichever you need:

```
$fruits = array_filter($fruits, function($var) use ($shelf_time) {
                                    return $var['shelf_life'] >= $shelf_time;
                                });
```

Comment: Nice answer with `array_filter()`, it would also reindex the array if the keys are numerical

Comment: @Rizier123: Yes, but they're not.  If it was numerical and needed to maintain keys I have a much better answer.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [unset](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.unset.php)

```
unset($fruits['apple']);
```

Comment: Trouble is finding 'apple' is the one to unseed :)